# keep value selected after submit in PHP

Tags: php

My php code is similar to below. If I select the option and submit, the value selected disappears. How can I make the selected value appear on the dropdown after submit also?

```
     <select name = "org">
      <?php
      $query = "select org from txtable group by org";
      $result = mssql_query ($query);
      while ($record = mssql_fetch_array ($result))
      {
      echo "<option value = '".$record[0]."'>". $record[0]. "</option>";
      }

     ?>
     </select>
```

Note: I already searched for similar questions but none of them really helped me.

Comment: Just use logic to output `selected="selected"` as an attribute for the selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <select name = "org">
  <?php
  $query = "select org from txtable group by org";
  $result = mssql_query ($query);
  while ($record = mssql_fetch_array ($result))
  {
    if($_POST['org'] == $record[0])
    {
        echo "<option selected value = '".$record[0]."'>". $record[0]. "</option>";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "<option value = '".$record[0]."'>". $record[0]. "</option>";
    }
  }

 ?>
 </select>
```

That takes the previous post variable and checks to see if it equals the value being found in the SQL result